# Yii2 How to break output of Listview in a new line

Tags: php, yii2

How to break output of Listview in a new line in listview widget [note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duN8S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column name is "note" and it contains lines break, define it as follows:

```
'note' => [
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return nl2br($model->note);
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

if using on html you can HTML syntax with BR otherwise use /n to make Enter or

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).